# Style thicker underline CSS

Tags: css, underline

I wanted to add a thicker underline to my h1 tags so I used "border-bottom" as suggested in multiple Stack Overflow questions. However, the border extended well beyond the text, so I decided to add the display property "inline-block" to make the border conform to the text's bounds. This, however, made the element lack a line break after the content. I know I could always add the "br" tag, but I'd prefer to keep that in my styling. Is there anything I can do? Here is my current CSS:

```
h1
{
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Just wrap the H1 tag in a block element, like a DIV. Or put the content that follows it in a block element...

Comment: Have a look at the CSS box model (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). Generally if you remove all of the padding and increase the margins, the border will match the text much better. I know that this doesn't quite answer the question, but is a different solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `display: table` instead.  It acts similar to inline-block in that it collapses down to to the width of its children, but prevents surrounding inline elements from flowing along side of it the same way an ordinary block element does.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/FvGxl

Comment: Thanks for this. Will the CSS purists be after my blood for it?

Comment: @J4G They shouldn't be. `display: table` != `<table>`.

Answer (score 3):

If the width of your `<h1>` text is fixed, you can set the `width` and keep it `display: block;`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image]

#### CSS:

```css
h1 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<h1>underlined</h1>
next line
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't always want border-bottom (eg, navigation item with padding), this method works better:

```
h1:after {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background: black; 
    display:block;
}
```

If you want more or less space between the text and the underline, add a `margin-top`.

If you want a thicker underline, add more `height`:

```
h1:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    background: black; 
    display:block;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```